# It's possible to make this in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm make a orders system food

I want to do this,When all the statuses of the dishes are "COMPLETE", the order automatically changes to complete

I have 4 tables

**1 ORDER**

ID_ORDER: OR00001

**STATUS: IN PROCESS/CHANGE AUTOMATICALLY "COMPLETE"**

CREATION_DATE: 17/07/2017

**3 DISH**

**1 DISH 
PASTA**

ID: PA00001

NAME: PASTA MIDELA

CHEF: JEFF

ID_ORDER: OR00001

STATUS: IN PROCESS

**2 DISH SALAD**

ID: SA00001

NAME: DIET SALAD

CHEF: ASTON

ID_ORDER: OR00001

STATUS: IN PROCESS

**3 DISH MEAT**

ID: ME00001

NAME: MEAT BBF

CHEF: JEFF

ID_ORDER: OR00001

STATUS: IN PROCESS

**How is it possible?** Thanks

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ORDER](
    [ID_OR] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ID_ORDER]  AS ('OR'+right('00000'+CONVERT([varchar],[ID_OR],(0)),(5))),
    [STATUS] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [CREATION_DATE] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_RR] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID_ORDER] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
END
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[1_DISH](
    [ID_D1] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ID_PASTA]  AS ('PA'+right('00000'+CONVERT([varchar],[ID_D1],(0)),(5))),
    [NAME] [varchar](20),
    [CHEF] [varchar](20),
    [STATUS] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ID_ORDER] [varchar](20)
 CONSTRAINT [PK_RR] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID_PASTA] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
END
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[2_DISH](
    [ID_D2] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ID_SALAD]  AS ('SA'+right('00000'+CONVERT([varchar],[ID_D2],(0)),(5))),
    [NAME] [varchar](20),
    [CHEF] [varchar](20),
    [STATUS] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ID_ORDER] [varchar](20)
 CONSTRAINT [PK_RR] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID_SALAD] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
END
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[3_DISH](
    [ID_D3] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ID_MEAT]  AS ('ME'+right('00000'+CONVERT([varchar],[ID_D3],(0)),(5))),
    [NAME] [varchar](20),
    [CHEF] [varchar](20),
    [STATUS] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ID_ORDER] [varchar](20)
 CONSTRAINT [PK_RR] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID_MEAT] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
END
GO
```

Comment: I am not trying to judge your design but I think it would be better if you combine the 3 dish table into single table. Just add column if you really particular on the number, e.g DISH_NO : 1 or 2 or 3. You can put trigger to check for those 3 table status and update your order table status when all complete

Comment: I agree with Martono -- you might think about having just one table for "Dish" or perhaps "Item" related to your Order table with a foreign key.

There are a lot of ways to get [Order] to be up to date. To be honest, I would probably either 1) use a stored procedure to update my dishes, and have a test as the last step and update order accordingly, or 2) remove the [Status] Column from [Order] and make a view called [OrderView] or [OrderInfo] that does the very simple is complete logic at read time.

Comment: First identify what your entitities and attributes, relationnships between entities, normalization etc. Check this link for understanding the basic DB design http://en.tekstenuitleg.net/articles/software/database-design-tutorial/intro.html

Comment: Dump your (I hardly dare to call this) data model. What if there's a fourth dish ordered, no desseert? You never expect more than 99999 orders? No Foreign Keys, why do you link using ID_ORDER instead of the identity?

Answer (score 1):

Here's some sample code that might help you.

Two tables are created: one for the **Orders** and the second for the **Dishes** that comprise an order.

I added a **DishType** column to the Dish table.
I changed the **Status** to be a `varchar` datatype.

```
declare @ORDERTABLE table 
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [STATUS] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [CREATION_DATE] [datetime] NOT NULL
)

declare @DISHTABLE table
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DISHTYPE] varchar(20),
    [NAME] [varchar](20),
    [CHEF] [varchar](20),
    [STATUS] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [ID_ORDER] int
)
```

Some sample data is inserted.

```
insert @ORDERTABLE (STATUS, CREATION_DATE) values
('IN PROCESS', getdate()),
('IN PROCESS', getdate());

insert @DISHTABLE (DISHTYPE, NAME, CHEF, STATUS, ID_ORDER) values
('PASTA','PASTA MIDELA','JEFF','IN PROCESS',1),
('SALAD','DIET SALAD','KIA','IN PROCESS',1),
('MEAT','MEAT BBF','BART','IN PROCESS',1),
('SALAD','CAESAR SALAD','KIA','IN PROCESS',2),
('MEAT','ROAST CHICKEN','BART','IN PROCESS',2);

update @DISHTABLE set STATUS = 'COMPLETE' where ID = 1;
update @DISHTABLE set STATUS = 'COMPLETE' where ID = 2;
update @DISHTABLE set STATUS = 'COMPLETE' where ID = 3;

select * from @DISHTABLE;
```

A simple way to automatically change the Order status: whenever you change the status of a dish, check how many dishes are in the order versus how many of the dishes are completed. If all dishes are complete then change the order status to complete as well.

```
declare @ORDERID int = 1;

update @ORDERTABLE 
    set STATUS = 'COMPLETE' 
where 
    ID = @ORDERID 
    and (select count(*) from @DISHTABLE where ID_ORDER = @ORDERID) = (select count(*) from @DISHTABLE where ID_ORDER = @ORDERID and STATUS = 'COMPLETE');


select 
    o.ID, 
    DISHES = (select count(*) from @DISHTABLE where ID_ORDER = o.ID),
    COMPLETED = (select count(*) from @DISHTABLE where ID_ORDER = o.ID and STATUS = 'COMPLETE'),
    o.STATUS
from @ORDERTABLE o;
```